# Consolidate result of different dates by scanning the data from file and output data of particular date

Tags: java, algorithm, hashmap, filereader

I have recently given interview with major MNC and faced a coding question. It was an inventory based question. Got a file which has inputs as:

> Date, name of fruit, no of fruits sold, total fruits.

```
**2018-06-01,apple,15,25 ;
2018-06-02,apple,13,25 ;
2018-06-03,apple,20,25 ; 
2018-06-01,mango,12,25 ;
2018-06-02,mango,19,25 ;
2018-06-03,mango,20,25 ;
2018-06-01,orange,15,25 ;
2018-06-02,mango,16,25 ;
2018-06-02,orange,14,25 ;
2018-06-03,orange,24,25 ;
2018-06-02,apple,18,25**
```

I have to iterate file and in the end print out the results how many fruits sold on 2018-06-02. Below is the code which i have writen

```
enter code here
public class Inventory {
            public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
                FileInputStream geek = new FileInputStream("/Users/preet/Desktop/test2.txt");
                InputStreamReader reader = new InputStreamReader(geek, StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
                BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(reader);
                List<String> lines = new ArrayList<String>();

                Map<String, Map<String, List<Integer>>> map = new HashMap<String, Map<String, List<Integer>>>();

                Map<String, List<Integer>> map2 = new HashMap<String, List<Integer>>();
                List<Integer> apple = new ArrayList<Integer>();
                List<Integer> mango = new ArrayList<Integer>();
                List<Integer> orange = new ArrayList<Integer>();
                String result = "";
                String line = null;
                String[] input = new String[10];
                int i = 0;
                while ((line = in.readLine()) != null) {
                    input[i] = line;
                    System.out.println("value at " + i + ":" + input[i]);
                    i++;
                }

                for (String a : input) {
                    String b[] = a.split(",");
                    if (b[1].equalsIgnoreCase("apple")) {
                        apple.add(Integer.parseInt(b[2]));
                        map2.put(b[1], apple);
                        map.put(b[0], map2);
                    } else if (b[1].equalsIgnoreCase("orange")) {
                        orange.add(Integer.parseInt(b[2]));
                        map2.put(b[1], orange);
                        map.put(b[0], map2);
                    } else if (b[1].equalsIgnoreCase("mango")) {
                        mango.add(Integer.parseInt(b[2]));
                        map2.put(b[1], mango);
                        map.put(b[0], map2);
                    }
                    if (map.containsKey(b[0])) {
                        Object value1 = map.get(b[0]);
                        map.put(b[0], map2);
                        } else
                        map.put(b[0], map2);
                }
                System.out.println("Fetching Keys and corresponding [Multiple] Values n");
                List<String> results = new ArrayList<String>();
                for (Map.Entry<String, Map<String, List<Integer>>> entry : map.entrySet()) {
                    String orange1 = null;
                    String apple1 = null;
                    String mango1 = null;
                    int a1 = 0;
                    int a2 = 0;
                    int a3 = 0;
                    Map<String, List<Integer>> values = entry.getValue();
                    for (Map.Entry<String, List<Integer>> entry1 : map2.entrySet()) {
                        String key = entry1.getKey();
                        if (key.equalsIgnoreCase("apple")) {
                            List l1 = entry1.getValue();
                            for (int j = 0; j < l1.size(); j++) {
                                a1 = (int) l1.get(j);
                            }
                            apple1 = entry.getKey() + " " + a1 + " apples";
                            results.add(apple1);
                        } else if (key.equalsIgnoreCase("mango")) {
                            List l1 = entry1.getValue();
                            for (int j = 0; j < l1.size(); j++) {
                                a2 = (int) l1.get(j);
                            }
                            mango1 = entry.getKey() + " " + a2 + " mangoes";
                            results.add(mango1);
                        } else if (key.equalsIgnoreCase("orange")) {
                            List l1 = entry1.getValue();
                            for (int j = 0; j < l1.size(); j++) {
                                a3 = (int) l1.get(j);
                            }
                            orange1 = entry.getKey() + " " + a3 + " oranges";
                            results.add(orange1);
                        }
                    }
                     System.out.println("Values = " + (values));
                }
                System.out.println("****" + results);
                  }
        }
```

Comment: I am confused. You didn't ask a question, and then you posted an answer, but in the answer you mention that you seem to be having trouble.

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please take the [tour] and familiarize yourself with the way this community works

Comment: @rmlan ya i have tried solving it didnot worked that's why i have posted.

Comment: @Preet Adding information to your question is very welcome, and your own attempt to solve the problem even more so. In this case please [edit the question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/50682592/edit) and add information there. Do not post supplementary information about the question as an answer. As you can seem that confuses people.

Comment: So what is your question?

Answer (score 1):

For an interview I would suggest the following as a first shot: iterate over the file. Split each line at commas using `String.split()`. If element 0 of the resulting array is identical to `2018-06-02`, parse the integer in element 2 (the no of fruits sold) using `Integer.parseInt()` and add to the total count.

An obvious thing missing from such a first shot is input validation. May first check that there is at least one line in the file. Check that each line ends with a semicolon. Remove it and any space before it before splitting. Check that the length of the array is 4. Use the one-arg `LocalDate.parse()` for parsing the date on each line and `Integer.parseInt()` to parse both the number sold and the total number. Validate that the number sold is less than or equal to the total number. May also check that the name is that of a known fruit.

Another thing is data modelling. Design a fruit class with a name field and a fruit sales class with a date, a total number and a number sold, for example.